# how to increment 1 every row after get row id in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i have a one question for increment +1 in every row
i have a sql table in that table have order_status column when new record created order_status will be store +1 then older record in that case if i have order status like 0 1 2 3 
but when user send me order status 2 for 5th record so in this case record no 5 will be store as a record status 2 but i need to change status aftr 2 like

```
2 will be 3, 3 will be 4, 4 will be 5
```

if its posible so please me sql query

Comment: you can use update ..but try explain better ... show proper data sample and expected result..eventually take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: sounds like you want to do something ridiculous. A new row comes in and in the insert trigger (or otherwise) you modify all the rows in the table. No, don't do that

Comment: thanks guys for replay your comment

Answer (score 1):

Use an `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET order_status = order_status + 1
WHERE order_status >= 2
```